# Не выводится шаблон страницы wordpress

Tags: wordpress

В админке при редактировании страницы не выводится блок шаблонов страниц у страницы, которое по дефолту является страницей для записей. На других страницах все в порядке. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: В WordPress шаблоны могут быть назначены только страницам.

Comment: @KAGGDesign ты не прав ;) Уже давно можно назначать любому типу контента

Answer (score 1):

> которое по дефолту является страницей для записей.

Не знаю что подразумевается под "страница записи", но для записей можно создать свой шаблон указав в заголовке `Template Post Type: post`.

Напр:

```
<?php
/*
Template Name: Мой шаблон записи
Template Post Type: post
 */
```

Подробнее см https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/#creating-page-templates-for-specific-post-types

Comment: Это само собой, но даже при таком раскладе не видно! Это первое, что я сделал.

Comment: @Lemp возможно надо включить блок в настройках экрана.